# SDWebImage iOS 8 performance

Tags: ios, scroll, ios8, sdwebimage

I have been using SDWebImage in my project for sometimes. It is working but all of iOS 8 users experience super laggy scrolling. I have updated the latest version of SDWebImage already but the problem doesn't seem to be solved. Has anyone experienced the same problem? How do I fix it?

Here is a simple code that I am using:

```
 [profileImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL profilePhotoURLString] placeholderImage:PROFILE_PHOTO_SMALL];
```

Comment: I think you should raise this as an issue [here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/new) so that it can help others as well!

Comment: did you have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Tung Vo i have experienced same issue with SDWebImage because it doesn't clear the the downloading queue and despite many efforts i wasn't successful in stopping the downloads of unwanted images and if there are too many images there would be memory issues. Try using AFNetworkings image downloader. Here is a [link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h).